# stripe checkout hangs Chrome for seconds after closing

Tags: javascript, stripe-payments

When opening and then closing (X in top right corner) the simple Stripe checkout popup it causes the latest Chrome browser hangs several seconds (2-5 seconds).

Test case: http://jsfiddle.net/ns2fezag/19/. Click the red button, close the dialog and after closing try to click in the edit field. The UI hangs for me. Does it occur for others (you) as well and does anyone have an idea on how to circumvent that?

edit: Even simpler example: http://jsfiddle.net/znpd4gLb/1/

And here some source code, Stack Overflow complains without it:

```
lorem ipsum
```

Comment: You try test hidden //e.preventDefault() in event click of #buySocks.
http://jsfiddle.net/ns2fezag/20/

Comment: I think in your code use e.preventDefault() it will stop all trigger when call, maybe it can cause your problem. https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/

Comment: @sonpham Strange, it still occurs for me, at about 30% of all tries http://jsfiddle.net/znpd4gLb/1/